# How to make attr_accessor work only in testing environment?

Tags: testing, rspec, sinatra, environment

I'm working with Sinatra and RSpec. I have this in lib/auth.rb

```
class Person
    attr_accessor :password if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'test'
    ....
```

I want to execute this code when I'm testing with Rspec, but it doesn't work. This is my spec file:

```
describe Person
    it 'should match the password' do
        @james = Person.new(foo, 'bar')
        @james.password.should == 'bar'
    end
end
```

I don't want `@james.password` to be accessible outside of this model, but to be able to access it from the Rspec file or in the testing environment. Is there any code to make `attr_accessor` work only in the testing environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually setting `ENV['RACK_ENV']` when running your tests?

Try adding

```ruby
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'
```

to the start of your test file.

Comment: Wow... It's work. Thanks matt. I didn't know if ENV['RACK_ENV'] is nil.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but rather than trying to edit your code to work for the test, you could use [`instance_variable_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get).
So, your spec would look like this:

```
describe Person
  it 'should match the password' do
    @james = Person.new(foo, 'bar')
    @james.instance_variable_get(:@password).should == 'bar'
  end
end
```

And it wouldn't require any changes to your `Person` class!